# If Dataframe column A is X check if column B values are in list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to create an error flag in a sperate column.
I am not sure how to check conditions between two different DF columns.

Example DF

```
    Category Item    Flag
0   Fruit    Apple     
1   Fruit    Apple        
2   Fruit    Beef    
3   Fruit    Kiwi    
4   Fruit    Orange
```

What I want to achive:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi']

if df['Category'] == 'Fruit'

check if df['Item'] is in fruits

if not append error
```

Expected output

```
    Category Item    Flag
0   Fruit    Apple   OK  
1   Fruit    Apple   OK     
2   Fruit    Beef    Error
3   Fruit    Kiwi    OK
4   Fruit    Orange  OK
```

Comment: What is the expected output if Category is something other than Fruit?

Comment: If there are different categories. There would be different lists corresponding to those categories.

Answer (score 2):

Using [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df["Flag"] = np.where(df["Category"].eq("Fruit") & df["Item"].isin(fruits), "OK", "Error")
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but it's missing the `Category` check. You could do `(df['Category'] == "Fruit") & (df["Item"].isin(fruits))`

Comment: Absolutely correct I assumed the extra check was redundant but I guess Beef could be in a fruits list for some odd reason or a Category value could be wrong

Comment: My first thought was "tuna", lol, which is both a fish and a cactus (prickly pear)

Comment: Edited thanks for the tuna knowledge lol

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick for just fruits, creating a new df.
You can loop through all Categories, and combine the dataframes if you want one dataframe.

```
temp_df = df[df['Category'] == "Fruit"]
temp_df['Flag'] = ['OK' if (x in fruits) else 'Error' for x in temp_df['Item']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple df.apply to check

```
df["Flag"] = df.apply(lambda x: "OK" if x["Category"] == "Fruit" and x["Item"] in fruits else "ERROR", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function that checks both input values
2. Use lambda function to apply it to each row.

```
def check(x, y):
    if y in fruits and x == "Fruit":
        return True
    else:
        return "Error"

df['Flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: check(x['Category'], x['Item']), axis=1)
```